# Database bottleneck identification using jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, database-performance, blazemeter

I have created JDBC Test Plan and i am using mysql database, with 'max number of connections:2' in 'connection pool configuration' but when i change it to 10 average response time increases.

My Question is 'max number of connections:2'in 'connection pool configuration' is referring to number of users?

I do not have ide about database performance testing, how database performance testing plan should be? i am assuming that increase number of users in thread group and report the response time. Can some one guid me with the sample database test plan as i do not know what component should be modified when testing for the performance.[image: Configuration]

Answer (score 1):

Number of connections != number of users.

This "Max Number of Connections" is applicable for [JDBC Connection Pool](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/ConsoleHelp/jdbc_connection_pools.html). JDBC Connections are very "expensive" to create hence normal practice is creating a pool so the connections can be established and used/reused by threads(users).

Ideally you should configure JDBC parameters to match your application settings, if you figure out that database responds slower due to the lack of available connections - you can test new configuration and suggest DBAs to change settings.

Number of users you should be setting on [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) level.

See [The Real Secret to Building a Database Test Plan With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/real-secret-building-database-test-plan-jmeter) article to learn more about concepts of database load testing using JMeter